# the list of the data is not listed

Tags: php, android, json

i am trying to connect my android project to the PHP page but it is not working what is the error i don't know why it is not working for me i put the internet permission

this is Site code where it check the http connection:

```
public class site  {
        static String response = null;
        public final static int getrequest =1;
        public final static int postrequest=2;
        public site(){}
        public String histosite (String url, int requestmothod){
            return this.histosite(url,requestmothod);
        }
        public String histosite(String urlsddress, int requestmothod,HashMap<String,String> params){
            URL url;
            String response= "";
            try {
                url= new URL(urlsddress);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15001);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15001);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                if (requestmothod == postrequest){
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                } else if(requestmothod == getrequest){
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GETRequest");
                }
                if(params != null){
                    OutputStream ostream = conn.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ostream,"UTF-8"));
                    StringBuilder requestresult = new StringBuilder();
                    boolean first = true;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: params.entrySet()){
                        if (first)
                            first=false;
                        else
                            requestresult.append("&");
                        requestresult.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
                        requestresult.append("=");
                        requestresult.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(),"UTF-8"));
                    }
                    writer.write(requestresult.toString());
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    ostream.close();
                }
                int reqresponsecode= conn.getResponseCode();
                if(reqresponsecode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
                        response += line;
                    }
                } else {
                    response = "";
                }
            }  catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }


    }
```

this is where the data should retrieved and presented :

```
public class Historical_Sites  extends ListActivity {
    private static final String url= "http://tourin.esy.es/php/historical.php";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS="posts";
    private static final String TAG_SITE_NAME = "Site_Name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ex);
        new getsite().execute();
    }
    private class getsite extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> siteslist;
        ProgressDialog prodialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            prodialog= new ProgressDialog(Historical_Sites.this);
            prodialog.setMessage("Please waite");
            prodialog.setCancelable(false);
            prodialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            site Site = new site();
            String jsonstr = Site.histosite(url,site.getrequest);
            Log.d("Response : ", ">" + jsonstr);
            siteslist= ParseJSON(jsonstr);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void requestres) {
            super.onPostExecute(requestres);
            if(prodialog.isShowing())
                prodialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Historical_Sites.this,siteslist,R.layout.list,
                    new String[]{TAG_SITE_NAME},new int[]{R.id.lis});
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ParseJSON( String json){
            if(json != null){
                try {
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> SiteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                    JSONObject Jsonobj= new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray HistoricalSites = Jsonobj.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                    for(int i=0 ; i<HistoricalSites.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c = HistoricalSites.getJSONObject(i);
                        String sitename = c.getString(TAG_SITE_NAME);
                        HashMap<String,String>HistoricalSite = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        HistoricalSite.put(TAG_SITE_NAME,sitename);
                        siteslist.add(HistoricalSite);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }else{
                Log.e("Service Handeller","No data recieved ");

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

this the json code :

```
{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","posts":[{"Site_Name":"Bahrain National Museum"},{"Site_Name":"Qalat al Bahrain site and museum"},{"Site_Name":"Boats Trips to Bu Maher Fort"},{"Site_Name":"Old Houses of Muharraq"},{"Site_Name":"Bait al Quran"},{"Site_Name":"Al Khamis Mosque"},{"Site_Name":"Arad Fort"},{"Site_Name":"Sheikh Salman Bin Ahmed Al Fateh Fort"},{"Site_Name":"Siyadi House"},{"Site_Name":"Siyadi Mosque"},{"Site_Name":"Al Jasra House"},{"Site_Name":"Al Jasra Handicrafts Centre"},{"Site_Name":"Al Fateh Mosque"},{"Site_Name":"Saar Settlement"},{"Site_Name":"Barbar Temples"}]}
```

Comment: look at this http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123

Comment: this example is not using HttpURLConnection is use method that is not supported by android studio now

Comment: conn.connect(); is missing in ur code

Comment: also it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
String getWebServiceTask(String requestURL,JSONObject postDataParams,String PostType)
{
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    int responseCode = 0;
    JSONObject responseObject = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(1500000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1500000);

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");  
        conn.setRequestMethod(PostType);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();

        if(postDataParams != null){
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(postDataParams.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

        responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        responseObject=new JSONObject();
        responseObject.put(AppConstants.API_RESPONSE_CODE, responseCode);
        responseObject.put(AppConstants.API_RESPONSE, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return responseObject.toString();
}
```

Comment: what AppConstants.API_RESPONSE_CODE mean

Comment: AppConstants.API_RESPONSE_CODE replace with "ResponseCode" and  AppConstants.API_RESPONSE with "Response"